# Bijection and Isomorphim in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let *A* and *B* be two well-ordered sets. Is it ture that *A* and *B* are isomorphic if *A* and *B* are bijective?

Motivation:
I am studying Bourbaki's *Elements of Methematics* and have just reached Sec 3.2, Chap 3 where the concept of $\mathbb{N}$ have not appeared yet but Bourbaki seems to have assumed Cantor–Bernstein theorem. I want to proof the theorem with the knowledge I have obtained from Bourbaki's work and if the above statement is ture the theorem is also ture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement above is **false**. For example, consider:

- The natural numbers with the usual ordering.
- The set $\{1-{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}\cup\{1\}$ with the usual ordering.

(The corresponding [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) are $\omega$ and $\omega+1$, respectively.)

These sets are each countable, so in bijection with each other. However, they're not isomorphic as well-orderings: the second has a greatest element but the first doesn't.